# Bootstrap Drop Down menu is not working

Tags: plugins, functions, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap dropdown is working when i added the jquery( https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js ) in footer and by deregistering wodpress default jquery.

When i disabling the default  jquery my plugins are not working.

Can any one help me on this please?

Comment: bootstrap loading in footer and main jquery loading in header

Comment: Or because default jQuery script packed with WordPress works in `noConflict` mode.

Comment: Check the scripts priority. The jQuery should be called first and after it all other libraries that depend on it. It could be that the bootstrap.js loads first and the jQuery loads after it. Can you share the console log (usually **f12**, then open the **console** tab, then second mouse button **save as**)

edit: Or share your website's url.

Comment: Jquery library is loading first. And i'm not getting any errors in console. the bootstrap dropdown menu shows expand child menu when click on it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem got solved by commenting the some codes in function.js(theme js folder) that generating "Expand  child menu" text.